# Cleaning user input before sending it in mail

Tags: php, security, email

I am using **PHPMailer** class to send mails. Some mails contain user input. Should I clean user input before inserting it to `mail body`? How to do this?

Tried to google for it but haven't fount anything useful.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should `ALWAYS` sanitize/clean user input to prevent code or SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Sanitation is **always** key when handling user input.

- You can use [`strip_tags`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to limit the HTML tags they're allowed to use, if any.
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will properly change things like `<` into `&lt;` so they can't be evaluated as HTML.
- If inserting content into a database, use the proper escape function:

  - PostgreSQL - [`pg_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)
  - mySQL - [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I am familiar with sanitizing data before inserting to databases. My question is about **mail injections**. Are thees functions (escaping functions) enough to prevent such kinds of attacks?

Comment: Yes, stripping tags is probably the most important.